# Best way to detect if a user leaves the page in React (i.e. refresh, close tab, or change url)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, analytics, metrics

Like the title says, I have a React project using react router and want to detect when a user leaves the page (i.e. refresh, close tab, or change url). I don't want to prompt them or anything (like with the Prompt component in react router) because the purpose of this is to track how long they were on the page so I can use it for analytics.

What's the best way to do this so I can emit a metric when the user leaves the page?

Comment: I think react has something called componentWillUnmount

Comment: window.onbeforeunload

Comment: Use the `beforeunload` event to handle page reloads, closing tabs, etc... and the normal `useEffect` cleanup function when the component is just unmounting.